# generate iframe with jpg using asp.net ajax

Tags: javascript, vb.net

I have a javascript function that works for downloading a dynamically created docx document. It launches word on the client which is exactly what I needed (at the time). Now I need to show a jpg in a separate window (actually launch the default jpg viewer at the client). I cannot see why this doesn't work.

Can someone shed some light on this?

```
function SendDownload(url) {
    //alert(url);
    var elemIF = document.createElement("iframe");
    elemIF.src = url;
    elemIF.style.display = "none";
    document.body.appendChild(elemIF);
}
```

Comment: If you don't mind using browser as "default jpg viewer", you can use simple `window.open(url);`

Comment: the client wants the save capability. they are being picky. i already have the image on another ajax tab, but they want the same functionality as the docx.